# How to implement solidjs-like Component Show in React

Tags: reactjs

```
import { Show } from 'component';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <Show
      when={false}
      fallback={
        <div>
          {console.log('FLASE')}
          THIS IS FALLBACK UI
        </div>
      }>
      {console.log('TRUE')}
      NOW U SEE ME
    </Show>
  );
};
```

```
import type { FC, PropsWithChildren, ReactNode } from 'react';

export type ShowProps = {
  when: boolean;
  fallback?: ReactNode;
};

const Show: FC<PropsWithChildren<ShowProps>> = ({
  when,
  fallback,
  children,
}) => {
  if (when) {
    return children;
  }

  return fallback;
};

export default Show;
```

The problem is in solidjs
children and fallback are calculated lazily
When the condition is not met, its content will not be calculated.
But passing the ReactNode directly in React doesn't seem to do the trick

Is there any good way?
BTW, I don't want to pass the function I know this works